# Third solution to a third order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution, given two independent solutions:

$(x-1)^2y'''+(1-x^2)y''+2xy'-2y =0 ,\,\, y_1=x ,\,\, y_2=e^x.$

I tried $v=\dfrac{x}{e^x}$ and $v=\dfrac{e^x}{x}$ to reduce order of the original ODE by one, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The third solution is $x^2+1$ but I can't find how!

Comment: try it with $y(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$

Comment: It results that $y(x)=Ax^2+Bx+A$ is solution, and since $Bx$ was already found, an other one is $A(x^2+1)$. But how we can find it if we don't know the answer is $x^2+1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $y = x u$ and you get an equation in $u$ with only $u'''$, $u''$ and $u'$ terms, i.e. with $v = u'$ you have a second order equation in $v$.
Next substitute $v = (e^x/x)' w$ and you'll get a first order equation in $w'$.